# iOS Static library - is it possible to include AdSupport.framework in my library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, xcode7, static-libraries

I'm using objective-c, xcode7.

I've created a static library that uses ASIdentifierManager, included in "AdSupport.framework".

Now when someone wants to use my *.a file, they have to include "AdSupport.framework" in their project as well.

Is it possible to include "AdSupport.framework" in my compiled *.a library so that others will not have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a system library. Include the requirement that they link to it in your integration instructions. If you're supporting a dependency manager like CocoaPods you can define this requirement in the PodSpec so that it is taken care of for them.